# guava - difference between Lists.transform(..., ...) and FluentIterable.from(...).transform(...)

Tags: java, list, filter, guava

What is the difference, if any, between

```
Lists.transform(list, function)
```

and

```
FluentIterable.from(list).transform(function).toList()
```

?

Comment: What does the javadoc say?

Comment: The javadoc of Iterables.list() does only state that it returns a list containing the elements. It does not state whether it is a view or not. Is it? If not, is that the only difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Lists.transform` returns a `List` that is a *view* of the original `List`. If you add or remove items in the original list, the view will change as well.

`FluentIterable.from(list).transform` similarly returns a transformed view of the original list, though as a `FluentIterable` rather than as a `List`. When you call `toList()` on it, though, you get back an `ImmutableList` which will *not* change if the original list changes (or ever for that matter).

Comment: Thanks, that is what I wanted to know. As said in the other comment, Iterables.list() does not state anything about whether it is a view or not.

Comment: @TereaJato: What is `Iterables.list()`? If you mean `FluentIterable.toList()`, it doesn't explicitly say "this does not return a view", but typically if a method _does_ return a view it will state that. Also, an `ImmutableList` can never be a view of something that could possibly be mutable.